# Confusing error about missing left parenthesis in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

SQLPLUS says I have missing left parenthesis with this statement in my sql script..

```
CREATE TABLE people(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2
);
```

I had uploaded my script with sftp, could that have played around with the script?

Comment: Have you tried putting a space between `people` and the opening parenthesis, in case the lack thereof is confusing the parser?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

VARCHAR2 is a type that needs a maximum size/length. Try something like...

```
varchar2(50)
```

Your missing left parenthesis is the parenthesis that surrounds the size.

```
CREATE TABLE people(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(50) 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a size for the VARCHAR2 data type.

E.g. VARCHAR2(30)

SQL*Plus is looking for the brackets around the VARCHAR2 size definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you didn't specify the character with datatype varchar2.
Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(20) );
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify the size of `Varchar2`.

For example:- `Name Varchar2(50)`

Note:- The maximum size of the Varchar2 is 4000.

Comment: This has already been posted / answered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10197710/2390075 Don't repost existing answers.