# Unable to find solution about missing left parenthesis in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Developer says missing left parenthesis.

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
>   00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 8 Column: 108

**Oracle SQL**

```
SELECT  t.DSA_NAME as "DSA NAME",
    t.REVISION as REVISION,
    XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS "PreProcessor Temp Table", 
    XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PostProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS "PostProcessor Temp Table"
    FROM 
    DSA_SOURCE t
    where XMLCAST (XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS VARCHAR2) like '%create%temp%'
    and t.REVISION IN (SELECT MAX(REVISION)
                     FROM DSA_SOURCE
                     GROUP BY DSA_NAME);
```

I have tried using `VARCHAR2(100)` instead of `VARCHAR` in CAST function, but then I am getting below **error**.

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:    *Action:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Stackoverflow answer sums it up quite nicely
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10197710/9822083

```
SELECT  t.DSA_NAME as "DSA NAME",
t.REVISION as REVISION,
XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS "PreProcessor Temp Table", 
XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PostProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS "PostProcessor Temp Table"
FROM 
DSA_SOURCE t
where XMLCAST (XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS VARCHAR2(50)) like '%create%temp%'
and t.REVISION IN (SELECT MAX(REVISION)
                 FROM DSA_SOURCE
             GROUP BY DSA_NAME);
```

VARCHAR2 is a type that needs a maximum size/length.
Your missing left parenthesis is the parenthesis that surrounds the size.

Comment: The question states that the OP already tried this and got a different error.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jedo said, you need to specify the size of the `varchar2`; but you mentioned in your question that you already tries that and got "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes". That is because the you are using `getStringValue()` within that `XMLCast()` call, when it is expecting an XMLType.

```
where XMLCAST (XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() AS VARCHAR2(100)) like '%create%temp%'
```

Either stick to just the `XMLCast()`:

```
where XMLCAST (XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()') AS VARCHAR2(100)) like '%create%temp%'
```

or remove that and only use `getStringVal()`:

```
where XMLTYPE(t.DSA_SOURCE).EXTRACT('//PreProcessor/statements/text()').getStringVal() like '%create%temp%'
```

... but not both.

---

You could also do this with `XMLQuery()` and `XMLExists()`:

```
select t.dsa_name as "DSA NAME",
  t.revision as revision,
  xmlquery('//PreProcessor/statements/text()'
    passing xmltype(t.dsa_source)
    returning content) as "PreProcessor Temp Table",
  xmlquery('//PostProcessor/statements/text()'
    passing xmltype(t.dsa_source)
    returning content) as "PostProcessor Temp Table"
from dsa_source t
where xmlexists('//PreProcessor/statements[matches(text(), ''create.*temp'')]'
  passing xmltype(t.dsa_source))
and (t.dsa_name, t.revision) in (
  select dsa_name, max(revision)
  from dsa_source
  group by dsa_name
);
```

I've changed the final clause too; with your version you're finding a list of revisions (all the highest revisions across all names), but then looking for any of those revisions for any name. I've amended it to look for the pairs of name and the maximum revision for that name.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=41eb239fa30b2e287b352f1370699871) (shown in 18c; this doesn't work in the 11gR2 version there, which is 11.2.0.2, but it does work in 11.2.0.4 and higher.)

If `dsa_source` is a `varchar2` you could avoid querying the table twice by using an analytic function, but that won't work with `clob` so probably isn't helpful.